# What is "current $," in Ruby's Array#join?

Tags: ruby, arrays

From Ruby's [`Array#join` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-join):

> **join(separator=$,) → str**
>   Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given separator. If the separator is nil, it uses current $,. If both the separator and $, are nil, it uses empty string.

What does `"current $,"` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$,` is another name for `$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR`, the output field separator for the print and Array#join. By default, it is `nil`. Confer [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [global variable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) named `$,`. The documentation says that if the separator is not specified, then the separator will be whatever the global `$,` variable happens to contain when the function is called.